# How to set up a continous integration in salesforce

Tags: continuous-integration

I am able to get the details of issues from salesforce. But how do I check if there is a change in any issues.

Comment: I'm afraid your question isn't very clear, nor do the tags help much. Could you consider expanding your question? What system needs to know of any changes? Where are the issues coming from? Where are they going?

Comment: Stevia is also an integration tool where you can get the all the issue details + the updated changes happening in salesforce. For example, If a project description is changed in salesforce, the same will be changed in Stevia also.

I am not sure how do they do the change in the C# code.
I want to implement the same to find if there is a change in any of the salesforce projects.

Comment: I create a query to get details from Salesforce. In order to get the updated issue details, I use the tag "Last_modified_date" available in salesforce.